# Delay in openFDA's drug recalls/enforcement reports?

Tags: openfda

It looks like there is a delay in the data served by the openFDA's enforcement report API. Right now, the most recent records in the responses from the endpoint are dated 6/18, but the most recent enforcement report from the FDA was released 7/16: http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/enforcement/enforce_rpt-Product-Tabs.cfm?action=Expand+Index&w=07162014&lang=eng

Are there plans to close this gap in the future?

Comment: Since this is a question only the folks who control `api.fda.gov` can answer, you might want to post it over on Github at https://github.com/fda/openfda/issues. Do note that since the codebase is open source, you should be able to run and update as frequently as you want and then only be bound by the source system, not openFDA.

Comment: Thanks, I put it up there: https://github.com/FDA/openfda/issues/24

Comment: Thanks for the report. We're aware of the delay and plan to have this fixed soon. Please note that because openFDA is a beta research project, APIs may not be updated on precisely the same schedules as existing FDA public data releases. (This reply was posted to the GitHub issue as well.)

Answer (score 2):

As has been updated on the github issue (https://github.com/FDA/openfda/issues/24), we're now updating this endpoint bi-weekly.